# PyDev / Aptana Studio 3 organize import order

Tags: python, import, aptana, pydev, aptana3

I'm using PyDev 2.4 on Aptana Studio 3.0.9.

In a specific script, I have a couple of imports. Illustrated:

```
from setupenv import setupenv
setupenv()

from front.models.source import Source
```

Organizing the imports will cause the order to be rearranged, so that the setupenv() call comes after the Source import - which will then fail.

Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour, in such a way that imports will be auto discovered, but not rearranged  in such a way that the `setupenv()` call will be moved?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading and calling setupenv.. just make your module automatically run it on import..

Examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class SetupEnv():
    def __init__(self):
        print "I'm SetupEnv"

class SetupEnvWrapper:

    print "These happen at import time."
    setup = SetupEnv()

    def __init__(self):
        print "I'm SetupEnvWrapper"
```

When you import those guys..

```
$ python -mSetupEnv
These happen at import time.
I'm SetupEnv
```